# How come can WinSCP or FileZilla not be listed in HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*).DisplayName

Tags: windows-10, powershell, filezilla, winscp

I am running a program to check whether specific software is installed on the server. For Google Chrome and Notepad++ I can use

```
(gp HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*).DisplayName -Match "Notepad"
```

but both WinSCP and FileZilla do not exist in the Uninstall list, however they are listed under Settings->Add/Remove Programs.

They are also not under
"Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WinSCP installer is a 32-bit application (so it can be used on both 32-bit and 64-bit systems).

As such, it writes to 32-bit registry path on 64-bit systems:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

I assume the same for FileZilla.